How to hide a sequence number in the messages that exposed to the public?
Here is the situation:

Alice sends msg1, msg2 and msg3 to Bob. Such messages are not always delivered to Bob following the same order. Bob needs to use key1 to decrypt msg1, use key2 to decrypt msg2, etc.
So Bob needs some hint from Alice as part of the message that tells the decipher about the sequence number of each message that as been sent by Alice. However, adding plain sequence number will make the message suspicious since the message is under censorship.
(I have a method that makes encrypted msg1, msg2 look innocent.)

To get around this issue I've got the following scheme in mind:
There might be a way that there's an array shared by Alice and Bob before they start the chat.
In such an array, there's a special character will suggest the sequence number.
For instance:

seq[0]=3!- : if Bob finds a '!-' from position [3], then seq=0
seq[1]=4-. : if Bob finds a '-.' from position [4], then seq=1

Any thoughts? Or any more advanced methods that I can use to make the sequence less obvious?

You specify that the messages may not be in a specific order, but if they are usually in order than this will leak the same information to an attacker. Transport protocols may also make it clear which order was expected. It is always possible to also encrypt the sequence number and have the encryption layer be entirely on top of the OSI stack.  Then you order the decrypted messages rather than the encrypted ones. You can use authenticated SIV mode if you want to use the sequence number as an IV. I'm assuming symmetric encryption here.

Please indicate the type of encryption that you plan to use. There is quite a difference between symmetric and asymmetric encryption.

Unless Bob has a huge number of keys, an alternative solution to your problem might be 'try all of them and see which one works'.  This doesn't answer your question - however it obviously doesn't leak any additional information in the ciphertexts, and so it may be worth considering.

Maybe it is an idea to permute the statically sized sequence numbers (using a cipher)? In principle that is what the scheme of DingoStiglitz already does, although it is using symbols rather than numbers or bits. My main issue with the proposed solution is that it seems unkeyed, so if the order is guessed once then the scheme will basically be broken.

To poncho: Yes I also thought about this solution. Iterate and looking for a matched key.

See this slide for the idea:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zA4JuVnJfZesj45zcK3G5T259E4QkZPEMi2f35o6Sgs/edit?usp=sharing
I have an implementation using Java and it works. Now it's just the issue about rotated order of the messages.

Can you not just use one of the Nonces are Noticed transforms? Here's a presentation and a video.
